# If PMBoK isn't itself a methodology, then what are the methodologies compatible with the PMI's standard for project management?

Tags: methodology, pmbok, pmi-framework

If PMBoK isn't itself a methodology, then what are the methodologies compatible with the PMI's standard for project management? One example is Waterfall. Are there any other examples?

Comment: Waterfall is not a methodology. It's a consequence of scheduling when you have to sequence work because of either hard or soft dependencies. That's when, not how.

Answer (score 1):

Basically PMBoK contains best practices and is not exactly related to any methodology.

More or less it could be applied to a big amount of methodologies. As an example here is an article of relationship between Agile software development techniques and those based on the Project Management Body of Knowledge (PMBOK® Guide):

https://www.pmi.org/learning/library/agile-pmbok-guide-project-management-scrum-6954

**So as an answer to your question: waterfall based, agile based methodologies.**

Answer (score 0):

PMBOK can be understood more as a compendium, a collection of practices. So the objective of this publication is to make it accessible and demonstrate the means of using these practices in a rational way.

This "guide" then offers some sense for the daily exercise of managing projects, where different components must be managed in time and space in order to enable their execution and proper delivery. When trying to interpret PMBOK as an end in itself it can compromise the main role of a Project Manager - Integrate. **Integrating requires the study and interpretation of a scenario and its possibilities**. Different scenarios may require different approaches and different tools.

Another important issue: managing projects requires the synergy of many personal and interpersonal skills. Considering that the objective is to achieve the project's purposes, many methodologies will be necessary and, probably, several will be able to adequately meet the objective.

Comment: But PMBoK contains the Standard for Project Management. Is this standard also a collection of practices or what?

Comment: Please consider that project management is complex in nature. The mere fact of applying established practices (by a group in a context) does not imply success.Recognizing the complex nature of design environments makes us more open to evaluation than the application of tools. In this sense, the effort to compile these methodologies, practices and tools must be understood as an opportunity for knowledge, not mandatory application.